# Array JavaScript com objecto JSON

Tags: javascript, json, array

Eu tenho os seguintes objectos:

```
var category = [
    {"category" : "fruity"},
    {"category" : "Cakes"}
]
```

e

```
var products = [
    {"description" : "Apple", "price" : 12.99, "category" : "Fruity"},
    {"description" : "Peach", "price" : 12.99, "category" : "Fruity"},
    {"description" : "Cake one", "price" : 12.99, "category" : "Cake"}
]
```

Pretendo disponibilizar essa informação no seguinte formato:

```
[
    {
        "category": "fruity",
        "products": [
            {
                "description" : "Apple",
                "price" : 12.99
            },
            {
                "description" : "Peach",
                "price" : 17.99
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "category": "Cakes",
        "products": [
            {
                "description" : "Cake one",
                "price" : 12.99
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Estou a um tempo trabalhar nisso e o resultado não tem sido satisfatório. Eis o meu código:

```
var j=0;
var i=0;
var entraP = { prod : [] }

if (category[i].category == products[j].category ){

  entrarP.c = category[i].category;

  while(category[i].category == products[j].category ){

    entrarP.prod.push(products[j]);

    j+=1;
  }
  i+=1;
}

console.log(entrarP);
```

Agradeço uma ajuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O código que está a utilizar para tentar agrupar os produtos tem algumas coisas que não jogam com o objetivo.

Começa por verificar se a primeira categoria joga com a primeira categoria do primeiro produto:

```
if (category[i].category == products[j].category ){
```

O que torna impossível de agrupar caso os produtos apareçam por outra ordem.

Tem também uma erro no nome da variável que fica com o resultado:

```
entrarP.c = category[i].category;
```

Que tinha sido anteriormente declarada como `entraP` e não `entrarP`.

Mas a lógica em si também não iria funcionar pois o `while` executa enquanto as categorias forem iguais:

```
while(category[i].category == products[j].category ){
```

Logo mal uma seja diferente este termina de imediato.

Como solução pode utilizar a função reduce do javascript para "reduzir" o array original de produtos de acordo com as suas categorias, da seguinte forma:

```
var produtosAgrupados = products.reduce(function(acumulador, corrente){

  //verificar se o acumulador(o resultado) já tem a categoria corrente obtendo a sua posição
  let indice = acumulador.map(x => x.category).indexOf(corrente.category);

  //-1 indica que não tem logo cria um novo objeto com categoria e produtos com 1, o corrente
  if (indice==-1){
    acumulador.push({
      category: corrente.category, 
      products: [{  
        description:corrente.description, 
        price:corrente.price}]
    });
  }
  else { //se ja tem a categoria adiciona nessa posição o novo produto
    acumulador[indice].products.push({  
        description:corrente.description, 
        price:corrente.price});
  }

  return acumulador; //retorna o objeto corrente para a próxima iteração
},[]); //começa o reduce com um array vazio
```

Para esta solução o array original que tinha apenas as categorias nem seria necessário.

Exemplo:

```js
var products = [
    {"description" : "Apple", "price" : 12.99, "category" : "Fruity"},
    {"description" : "Peach", "price" : 12.99, "category" : "Fruity"},
    {"description" : "Cake one", "price" : 12.99, "category" : "Cake"}
];

var produtosAgrupados = products.reduce(function(acumulador, corrente){

  let indice = acumulador.map(x => x.category).indexOf(corrente.category);

  if (indice==-1){
    acumulador.push({
      category: corrente.category, 
      products: [{  
        description:corrente.description, 
        price:corrente.price}]
    });
  }
  else {
    acumulador[indice].products.push({  
        description:corrente.description, 
        price:corrente.price});
  }
  
  return acumulador;
},[]);

console.log(produtosAgrupados);
```

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda. Funciona perfeitamente.